The dependency of remote app in micro frontend 'is not defined'
I develop a web app that uses NX, Angular and Micro-Frontend architecture.
I call the container: Shell, and the remote app: MF-1
In the MF-1 I use Snapsvg. And then import MF-1 to Shell then it returns Snap is not defined
I can resolve the issue if I add snapsvg.js to scripts in project.json of the Shell. But when I do the same in MF-1, it didn't work.
I tried some third party like Plotlyjs and the errors are the same.
Here is the repo : https://github.com/skordesign/gauge-chart-svg

Please share your webpack.config files that show your configuration.

@BizzyBob I've updated the description, you can check out the repo
